# Changing the outline of a DataGridViewRow

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, graphics, gdi+

If a certain condition is met I want to change the outline of the `DataGridViewRow` to blue to have it stand out. I know it isn't the `BackColor` since it changes the row's background color. I have tried to change the `ForeColor` to Blue but nothing changes. I wouldn't believe it is the selection styles since that behavior isn't what I am looking for. Any suggestions to get this behavior?

`item` below is a DataGridViewRow.

```
item.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue
item.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue
```

Thanks to help from Jimi.

I added to my datagridview.Paint

```
Dim visibleColumsWidth As Integer = dataGridView.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible)
Dim y As Integer = dataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(Column.DisplayIndex, rowIndex, True).Top
Dim rect As New Rectangle(dataGridView.RowHeadersWidth, y, visibleColumsWidth, item.Height - 1)
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, rect)
```

Comment: Do you want the whole selected row to be colored (i.e. the whole background of the row) or just the frame of the row? What do you mean by changing the outline?

Comment: @MarkusAnd Right now the colors of my rows rotate between Grey and White. Around certain rows I want to change the line or border color that surrounds that row with Blue.

Comment: Handle the [CellPainting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting?view=netframework-4.8) event and draw a rectangle when that certain condition is met. See the example there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the [RowPostPaint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowpostpaint) or [RowPrePaint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowprepaint) events to to paint the border of one or more Rows, based on specific conditions.

Here, I'm using the **`RowPostPaint`** event handler, since you may have already some painting procedure in your DataGridView: `RowPostPaint` allows to paint over an already drawn Row, redefining some details. There's no **`e.Handled`** property to set, since the drawing has already been performed at this point.

<sub>The `Handled` property is used to specify whether the event handler has completely handled the event or whether the system should complete the process.</sub>

- As usual, the bounding rectangle need to be adjusted, because of the way GDI+ draws this shape.
- You probably don't want to outline the row Header, which is included in the **`e.RowBounds`** value, so we need to subtract the [**`DataGridView.RowHeadersWidth`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheaderswidth) from the `e.RowBounds.Width`.
- The outline should be applied only to the visible Columns, so we can use the [**`DataGridView.Columns.GetColumnsWidth()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.getcolumnswidth) method to get this measure, specifying **`DataGridViewElementStates.Visible`** as the Column state.

► Replace `[Some Condition]` with the condition that should generate the outlining in your context.

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_RowPostPaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowPostPaint
    If [Some Condition] Then
        Dim visibleColumsWidth As Integer = dataGridView1.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible)
        Dim rect = New Rectangle(dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth, e.RowBounds.Top - 1, visibleColumsWidth, e.RowBounds.Height)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, rect)
    End If
End Sub
```

If you instead want to outline a single cell, then handle the [CellPainting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting) event:

Here, we paint all parts but *override* the Cell border default drawing, using the `e.Graphics.DrawRectangle()` method. The Cell bounding rectangle measure is slightly different, adapted to how the cell's internal borders are painted, so the new border overlaps the default one.

We also set `e.Handled = True`, to notify that the drawing has been handled and there's no need to do anything else.

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellPainting
    If e.RowIndex < 0 OrElse e.ColumnIndex < 0 Then Return
    If [Some Condition] Then
        Dim rect = New Rectangle(e.CellBounds.X - 1, e.CellBounds.Y - 1, e.CellBounds.Width, e.CellBounds.Height)
        e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, True)
        e.PaintContent(e.CellBounds)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rect)
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the rendering with the current values:

[image: DataGridView RowPostPaint CellPainting]

If you prefer to draw the border inside the Cells' bounds (or use a thicker Pen), move Left/Top down 1 pixel and shorten the height by 1 pixel.

Comment: This might work. Just have to figure out what the best event to clear the list that validates the condition. Right before the Paint happens

Comment: You should know what is the condition that generates the outlining. A specific `Cell.Value`? A specific `Row.Index`? A calculated Value? All of the above? Just apply the condition (also checking:  `if e.RowIndex < 0 OrElse e.ColumnIndex < 0)`

Comment: In `RowPostPaint`, `e.RowIndex` is never `< 0`.

Comment: The condition is the first time a value comes in. We show a list of files. So when the file name changes we highlight the first record with blue.

Comment: So, is the DataSource a `List(Of class)`? You could add a hidden `boolean` Column that specifies True/False when the file is new/old. Check that Row's `Cell.Value` and *Paint it Blue* ©® if the `True` condition is met.

Comment: Right now I am trying to get it to work with DataGridView.Paint. So I can calculate each row at once instead of handling each individually.

Comment: No, don't do that. The Paint event is not what you need here. It's related to the Control itself (the container), not it's content. `RowPrePaint`, `RowPostPaint` and `CellPainting` are the events that handle the inner composition. When you have determined which is the event that best fits your scenario (`RowPostPaint`, based on your description), use that as shown here, there's nothing else you need to do.