# How to draw a border when cell is in edit mode in datagridview in vb..net?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, border, cell

Here is my code from onpaint event. Works OK until I resize the form, than I get different glitches. Man such a stupid thing and I lost like 3 hours on it. Any help appreciated.

```
     Using backGroundPen = New Pen(e.CellStyle.BackColor, 1)
            Using gridlinePen = New Pen(Color.Black, 1)
                Using selectedPen = New Pen(Color.FromArgb(254, 169, 62), 1)
                    'Using selectedPen = New Pen(Color.Red, 1)
                    Dim topLeftPoint = New Point(e.CellBounds.Left - 1, e.CellBounds.Top)
                    Dim topRightPoint = New Point(e.CellBounds.Right - 1, e.CellBounds.Top)
                    Dim bottomRightPoint = New Point(e.CellBounds.Right - 1, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1)
                    Dim bottomleftPoint = New Point(e.CellBounds.Left - 1, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1)
                    If e.ColumnIndex > -1 And e.RowIndex > -1 AndAlso sender.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).IsInEditMode Then
                        e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All And Not DataGridViewPaintParts.Border)
                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(selectedPen, New Rectangle(e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Top, e.CellBounds.Width - 1, e.CellBounds.Height - 1))
                        e.Handled = True
                    Else
                        e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All And Not DataGridViewPaintParts.Border)
                        If e.RowIndex = -1 Then e.Graphics.DrawLine(backGroundPen, topLeftPoint, topRightPoint)
                        If e.ColumnIndex = -1 Then e.Graphics.DrawLine(backGroundPen, topLeftPoint, bottomleftPoint)

                        If e.RowIndex = sender.RowCount - 1 Then
                            e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridlinePen, bottomRightPoint, bottomleftPoint)
                        Else
                            e.Graphics.DrawLine(backGroundPen, bottomRightPoint, bottomleftPoint)
                        End If

                        If e.ColumnIndex = sender.ColumnCount - 1 Then
                            e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridlinePen, bottomRightPoint, topRightPoint)
                        Else
                            e.Graphics.DrawLine(backGroundPen, bottomRightPoint, topRightPoint)
                        End If

                        If e.RowIndex > 0 Then e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridlinePen, topLeftPoint, topRightPoint)
                        If e.ColumnIndex > 0 Then e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridlinePen, topLeftPoint, bottomleftPoint)
                        e.Handled = True
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: [Changing the outline of a DataGridViewRow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61106187/7444103). Apply to just the Cell that enters Edit mode. Don't use the `DataGridView.Paint` event: CellPainting, RowPrePaint or RowPostPaint or are the events you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DataGridView.EditingControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrol) is parented to the [DataGridView.EditingPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingpanel).  Knowing that, it is simple to draw a custom border for the `DataGridView.EditingPanel` by subscribing to its `Paint` event by calling [ControlPaint.DrawBorder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawborder).

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
  MyBase.OnLoad(e)
  AddHandler DataGridView1.EditingPanel.Paint, Sub(s As Object, pe As PaintEventArgs) ControlPaint.DrawBorder(pe.Graphics, New Rectangle(Point.Empty, DataGridView1.EditingPanel.Size), Color.FromArgb(254, 169, 62), ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)
End Sub
```

Comment: EditingPanel <- `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @JQSOFT, I don't know how you managed to get a NRE as the [EditingPanel Property](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/R/480c033e401988b8.html) is designed not to return a null reference.  Did you by chance use `EditingControl` instead?

Comment: _Did you by chance use EditingControl instead?_ Exactly that was the reason. My apologies again++

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I used, bases on the answer from TnTinMnm, tx.

```
Private Sub paint_datagrid_edit(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs)
    Dim tobjname, objectid
    objectid = get_object_id_by_control(sender.parent.Name)
    tobjname = LCase(objects(objectid).objectref)
    If tobjname = "gridname" Then
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, sender.clientrectangle, Color.FromArgb(255, 128, 67), ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)
    End If
End Sub
```