# How do I trigger the Painting of a rectangle over top of a DataGridView by cellmouse/click?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, onclick, paint

**How do I trigger the *instantaneous* painting of a rectangle over the top of some specific cell** `[destination: col2, row4]` **in a DataGridView by an entirely different cell** `[trigger: col1, row3]` **being clicked?**

Obviously I picked two random cell locations and I have tried to simplify my problem to the basic chunks. Clearly they cannot be forced as is to work together. I don't have a deep enough understanding of the event handler to call one event within the other due to lack of common signatures. I think frustration has clouded my vision and ability to see any logical possibilities.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Paint  
    Using ColBlue As New SolidBrush(Color.Blue)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(ColBlue, x, y, width, height)
        'TODO: decide loc and rect size
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub Datagridview1_CellMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles Datagridview1.CellMouseClick
    'TODO: Gain a better understanding of the event handler
End Sub
```

My intuition tells me to write a custom sub or function, but I am not certain what they require, which eventargs to use or not use.

Comment: You don't call an event. Events are raised by an object in response to something happening. You have to make that thing happen to raise that event. In the case of `Paint` events, you call `Invalidate` on a control and it will then raise a `Paint` event and repaint the invalidated area. If you want to force that `Paint` event to be handled immediately then you can call `Update`. If you call `Refresh` then that will call `Invalidate` with no arguments, so invalidate the entire control, and then call `Update`. Avoid invalidating the entire control if possible as it is slow.

Comment: This is how you handle the drawing of Rows/Cells bounds: [Changing the outline of a DataGridViewRow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61106187/7444103).  To draw the border of a Cell, use the `CellPainting` event. These events are triggered quite often. To force it, as mentioned, `Invalidate()` a rectangle that represents the Cell's bounds (you can use the value returned by `GetCellDisplayRectangle()`). -- You need to let the code in the event handler know that a Cell needs custom rendering. You can use a `List(Of DataGridViewCell)`, then add/remove Cells from this list.

Comment: If you need something a little more *descriptive* (different Colors, different Pens etc.), you can build a class object that contains the details used to render Cells in different ways. When the event is raised, check whether the current Cell (determined by `[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]`) is included in the list. When it is, draw its borders as defined by the properties of the class object that references the Cell. -- You also need to define the logic that adds/removes Cells from the list. You haven't described this in the question: it's actually the only part that matters.

Comment: If you want to trigger this coloring when the user “mouse clicks” on a cell, is there some reason you do not use the grid's `CellClick` event for this coloring? Granted, the paint event will fire when the cell is clicked, but it will also fire when no cell has been clicked. Is there something you need to do that can not be accomplished in the grids `CellClick` event? And without question, you need to clarify the relationship between the clicked cell and the colored cell. What determines which cell should be colored when cell X is clicked?

Comment: Thanks for all your help thus far.  Following your advice Jimi, I think I have everything sorted out, except for the List(of). I can't figure out how to programmatically add the desired cells to the list beforehand. obviously, this wont work:
'Dim currentCells As New List(Of DataGridViewCell)
            currentCells.Add(.GetCellDisplayRectangle(5, 1, False))'
Oh, I'm using:
 Using ColBlue As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Blue))
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(ColBlue, currentCells)
End Using

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) for the patience in pointing out the main pieces required for my solution.

A simplified version of my code for those that find themselves lost and unable to trigger the painting a rectangle by mouse click.

**Results** [code]

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   ‘Init new list of rectangles
   Dim bluegradeT As New List(Of Rectangle) From {}‎
   Dim ablue As New Rectangle

   ‘Programmatically adding the cells I want to paint to my list beforehand
   bluegradeT.Add(DgvTall.GetCellDisplayRectangle(5, 1, False))
   bluegradeT.Add(DgvTall.GetCellDisplayRectangle(7, 2, False))
   bluegradeT.Add(DgvTall.GetCellDisplayRectangle(5, 5, False))
   bluegradeT.Add(DgvTall.GetCellDisplayRectangle(5, 3, False))
   bluegradeT.Add(DgvTall.GetCellDisplayRectangle(6, 2, False))
   bluegradeT.Add(DgvTall.GetCellDisplayRectangle(4, 2, False))
End Sub
Private Sub DataGridView1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Paint
   ‘I have multiple paint events of different colors that I wanted triggered by clicking
   ‘specific cells in the dgv
   If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 2 Then
    If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex = 1 Then
    ‘so if the clicked location is {2,1}, then paint
       Using ColBlue As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Blue))
       ‘this particular brush paints blue at 50 opacity 
        For Each ablue As Rectangle In bluegradeT
        ‘use a loop to retrieve all the rects stored for this paint
           e.Graphics.FillRectangle(ColBlue, ablue)
        Next
       End Using
    End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseClick
   If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Selected Then
    If DataGridView1.Columns.(e.ColumnIndex).Selected Then
    ‘If some cell has been selected…
        DataGridView1.Invalidate(ablue)
        ‘trigger painting of dgv, but only in the area of tbe rectangles list
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
        ‘to make sure the control updates immediately
    End if
    End If
End Sub
```

### Notes

This began as an experiment to see what methods out on the internet can achieve the best color mixing by the required amount of work. I only really found an endless discussion board post with C++ theories and in various methodologies. I could see the only native method—aside from my clever trick--is `colorblend().` Initially, color blend seemed impossibly more complex than my concept, but in truth, it is probably easier than I thought. [I’m sure someone else has done this before me, but I don’t care, today it’s my technique] Overall, it does an excellent job in combining colors that look natural by overlapping semi-transparent color rects on top of already painted DGV cells on the fly. It is undoubtedly faster than mixing colors by hand in Photoshop.